# Ponctuations mélangées, ? et :

Tags: ponctuation

> Quelles sont les couleurs chaudes dans la liste suivante :
>
> - Rouge
> - Vert
> - ...

Dans l'exemple ci-dessus j'ai une phrase qui introduit une liste à puce. Elle se termine donc par deux points.

Sauf que c'est également une question, donc elle devrait se terminer par un point d'interrogation.

Quelle est la règle à suivre ? Met-on les deux ponctuations à la suite (ce qui me paraît bien lourd) ou bien une seule (et dans ce cas précis laquelle) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La succession de ces deux ponctuations me parait douteuse.

J'écrirais:

> Quelles sont les couleurs chaudes dans la liste suivante ?
>
> - Rouge.
> - Vert.
> - ...

ou

> Indiquer quelles sont les couleurs chaudes dans la liste suivante :
>
> - rouge ;
> - vert ;
> - ...

Note: dans le premiers cas, le point d'interrogation termine la phrase. Chaque élément de la liste est donc une phrase à part entière qui doit commencer par une majuscule et se terminer par un point. Dans le deuxième cas, le deux-points introduit une liste qui fait partie de la même phrase. Il n'y a donc pas de majuscules. Les éléments sont séparés par des points-virgules, les puces n'ayant pas valeur de ponctuation. Le dernier élément doit être terminé par un point.

Answer (score 1):

Je suggérerais de

1. reformuler la question afin de n'utiliser que les deux-points (":")
   avant la liste dont les éléments commencent avec une minuscule et
   sont suivis d'un [point-virgule](http://aidenet.eu/grammaire01c.htm#pointvirgule) et
2. utiliser une question directe (avec un point d'interrogation) suivie de la liste où tous
   les éléments commencent avec une majuscule et sont suivis d'un
   point-virgule (";").

Answer (score 1):

Le problème, ce sont naturellement les points de suspension.  Si on reformule sans, il n'y a pour moi aucune hésitation.

> Quelles sont les couleurs chaudes dans la liste suivante :
>
> - rouge,
> - vert,
> - autre ?

Remarquez les minuscule et la virgule qui peut-être remplacée par un point-virgule, en particulier si l'opération rend le texte homogène.

Avec les points de suspension, j'hésite entre

> Quelles sont les couleurs chaudes dans la liste suivante :
>
> - rouge,
> - vert,
> - ... ?

et

> Quelles sont les couleurs chaudes dans la liste suivante :
>
> - rouge,
> - vert,
> - ...

Answer (score 0):

sans référence autre que mon « instinct » typographique, je ponctuerais naturellement comme suit:

> Quelles sont les couleurs chaudes dans la liste suivante ?
>
> - rouge,
> - vert,
> - …

à noter qu'on ne met pas de point (et donc pas de majuscule) entre les éléments d'une liste, mais une virgule ou un point virgule.

> Met-on les deux ponctuations à la suite ?

Quoi qu'il en soit, il est hors de question de mettre deux ponctuations à la suite. Mis à part l'enchaînement avec des double chevron pour une citation, je ne crois même pas qu'il y ai un quelconque exemple autorisé en français.

Comment: Bien sûr qu'on peut mettre deux ponctuations à la suite ! Copier du *Lexique des règles typographiques en usage à l'imprimerie nationale* :  « Les points de suspension, qui marquent une suppression, ou une interruption ou un sous-entendu, s'emploient toujours au nombre de trois. Ils laissent subsister la ponctuation normale (selon le sens, précédant ou suivant celle-ci) excepté le point final d'une phrase ou de certaines abréviations, qui disparaît ou plutôt se trouve confondu avec eux. » Le point d'interrogation, donc, se met avant les trois points. et sans espace semble-t-il.